# Showing large amount of data

Tags: java, user-interface, datahistory

What is the general guideline on displaying large volume of data in UI?

One approach came to my mind was to load few records initially and then based on user input load subsequent records.

Are there any resources available from where I can learn? This is developed in Java (Both the back-end and the client).

Comment: You can implement pagination as well.

Comment: Are we talking about record-based data?

Comment: yes, it is record-based data

Answer (score 0):

My guidance: go "JViewPort" and start from there. This class is especially designed for large amounts of data.

It provides the abstractions to distinguish between data that can be "viewed" - and data that is not "required" right now.

Answer (score 0):

Sending only what the client requires is always a good idea.

One common idea is to use a DTO - Data Transfer Objects which only contains the data used by the client/viewport - you can convert your real objects to those DTOs both for speed and security.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send the most minimal as possible data to the client, consider you might cause massive delays and "slow script popups" on the browser if you send large amount of data.

A good approach is to paginate the data you want to show. So for example you would show a fixed amount of data and then when user scrolls or clicks a button then it will retrieve from the server the next set of data to display.

Pure Java is not written for client side , although there are frameworks such as GWT that will allow you to write Java for the client side, however the client side Java code will be translated to JavaScript during compilation.

Finally, paginating approaches should be available to provide best user experiences on professional UI frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Pagination ...

- Pagination is used for such things as displaying a limited number of results in UI
- Pagination can be handled client-side or server-side. Server-side pagination is more common. Client-side pagination can be used when there are very few records to be accessed.